# Redirect in Liferay after valid form submit?

Tags: java, spring, liferay

How to do this with liferay in Spring controller?

```
    if (bindingresult.hasErrors()) {
        return "myJspName";
    }
    return "redirect:/somePage";
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your code is in portlet action phase, you can redirect using the actionresponse object, for example:

```
actionResponse.sendRedirect("/somepage")
```